# MySQL query: help needed

Tags: mysql

I have two integer columns in a table where the first column is populated with some random numbers and the second column is empty. Now is it possible to sort the first column in ascending order and at the same time sort it in descending order and display as the second column? I have the example of the table below.

Initial Table:

```
col1   col2
 5
 7
 3
 9
 2
```

Output:

```
col1   col2
 2      9
 3      7
 5      5
 7      3
 9      2
```

Comment: Is there any use for this, or dis you just want to ask a question?

Comment: I came across this question, and I was curious to find out how to write a query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tb1.col1,tb2.col2 FROM 
  (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank, id as col1 
    FROM your_table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) as r 
    ORDER BY id ASC) as tb1 
JOIN
  (SELECT @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 as rank, id as col2 
    FROM your_table, (SELECT @rownum2:=0) as r 
    ORDER BY id DESC) as tb2
ON tb1.rank = tb2.rank
```

Comment: I get this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`

Comment: dammit at least change the column name based on your table... change `id` with `col1` or `col2`...

Comment: Sorry, I was confused a bit. Now its working perfectly. Thanks a  lot.